# Await not working on model.fit of Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I was following Tensorflow.js example
but for some reason, the browser complains with `await` keyword in front of `model.fit`.

The error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

The sample code I ran:

```
const model = tf.sequential({
    layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [10]})]
});
model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
for (let i = 1; i < 5 ; ++i) {
    const h = await model.fit(tf.ones([8, 10]), tf.ones([8, 1]), {
        batchSize: 4,
        epochs: 3
    });
    console.log("Loss after Epoch " + i + " : " + h.history.loss[0]);
}
```

I have verified that model.fit returns a `Promise`
I have tried it on safari as well as chrome.

I can go around this issue with .then but I would like to use await if I can.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: await can only be used in an async function. If this is top level code in node, just wrap it in an async IIFE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await` keyword only is available in async functions, so you have to wrap it in one.

The easiest way to do that, that keeps the scope is this:

```
(async () => {
   yourStuffHere
})();
```

which creates an anonymous async arrow function that calls itself upon creation.

Or if you don't need the whole thing to be asynchronous you can use the "older" method for async functions, by using `.then()` which runs the given callback function when the async function is finished:

```
model.fit(...).then(h => {
   console.log("Loss after Epoch " + i + " : " + h.history.loss[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the enclosing function as an `async` function, like:

```
async function yourFunction() {
  const model = tf.sequential({
    layers: [tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [10] })]
  });
  model.compile({ optimizer: "sgd", loss: "meanSquaredError" });
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
    const h = await model.fit(tf.ones([8, 10]), tf.ones([8, 1]), {
      batchSize: 4,
      epochs: 3
    });
    console.log("Loss after Epoch " + i + " : " + h.history.loss[0]);
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you would need to use `then`:

Comment: Hi, I just tried to run your function, the code after model.fit() is never executed, no errors in a console. CPU at 0%. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: Oh, seems like the browser tab should be active, for TF.js to run :D